# json - self referenced data into tree

Tags: javascript, json, tree, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a list of items in the form

ID - PARENT ID - NAME

That list is in a JSON like the following

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "name": "item 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "name": "item 2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "name": "item 3"
    }
]
```

How can I transform it into a nested list like this using javascript? (with no limit to the nesting level)

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "name": "item 1",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "item 3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "name": "item 2"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's almost one liner in python (assuming only one child per parent)

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

Data = '[{"id": 1,"parent_id": 0,"name": "item 1"},
         {"id": 2,"parent_id": 0,"name": "item 2"},
         {"id": 3,"parent_id": 1,"name": "item 3"}]'
List = json.loads(Data)
[[IItem.update({'children' : List.pop(List.index(Item))})  for IItem in List if Item['parent_id'] == IItem['id']] for Item in List]
Data = json.dumps(List)
pprint(Data)
```

If you need multiple children this changes things  a little.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the delay! I'm looking for a JS solution